# Testing the influence of variables on a separate correlation

Tags: regression, correlation

I've searched for solutions for a while but could not find any, perhaps once I learn the proper terminology available information online will pop out. I would like to know how much certain variables influence the correlation of another variable to an outcome variable.

**Problem:**
Imagine 100 forests with varying initial vegetative biomass, each suffering a discrete pest infestation event. It was found that the amount of initial biomass was strongly correlated to consumptive loss of biomass due to the pest invasion. Say it was noticed that for some satellite metric for forest "greenness", forests of greenness below 1 had a R^2 for biomass-consumption of 0.2 while those above 1 had R^2 of 0.8.

**Questions:**
How could one provide statistical significance for this difference in R^2? How can one justify the point of greenness 1 to test this relation when selecting different greennesses levels for categorization gives different results? Is it possible to find an unbiased function continuous over greenness or a proper bin size to model this relation?

Secondly, is it possible to create a model to see the contributions of several variables on the biomass-consumption relationship. For example, the contributions of greenness, climate, vegetation species, canopy height, etc.

**Goal:**
The goal is to determine how much a particular forest's pest consumption can be predicted by its biomass, since this is a factor that can be targeted for management. Variables predicting the biomass-consumption relation strength do not necessarily have to predict total consumption itself.

**Attempt:**
What I have tried so far is subsample the 100 plots and get an R^2 from regression of biomass and consumption, and roll that subsample across forest biomass for the all the plots, and check for a significant regression of those R^2 values to greenness. For example, take R^2 for the 10 lowest biomass forests and their consumption, R^2 for the 10 lowest, shifted 1 over, etc. Though, depending on subsample size, the results are drastically different, and the significant of the regression values aren't considered.

Is there a sound approach for this? Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Are you just looking for moderator analysis / an interaction term? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderation_(statistics)